# not able to take particular id from automatically from another table

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure like this:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[ParkingDeatailsReportnew] 
  @locid INTEGER, @startdate nvarchar(100),@enddate nvarchar(100)
 as
begin
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
  @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(Vtype)      from VType_tbl FOR XML PATH(''),   TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,1,'')
set @query = 'SELECT Date, ' + @cols + '  from  ( select v.Vtype, convert(date, dtime) as Date 
  from Transaction_tbl t inner join VType_tbl v   on t.vtid = v.vtid  where dtime between ''' + @startdate + ''' and ''' + @enddate +  '''and locid =  ' + (select l.Locid from Location_tbl l) 
 + '  ) d pivot ( count(Vtype)     for Vtype in (' + @cols + ')  ) p '
execute(@query)
end
```

while executing this query I get following error:

> expects parameter '@locid', which was not supplied.i want to take all locid from my location table

Comment: Please review your title which has no meaning.

Answer (score 0):

You Stored Procedure failing to run since you it is expecting get parameters `@locid`, `@StartDate`, and `@EndDate`

```
EXEC ParkingDeatailsReportnew   
   @logid = [yourvalue], @StartDate = '[somedate]', @enddate = 'someEndDate'
```

for example:

```
EXEC ParkingDeatailsReportnew   
   @logid = 1234, @StartDate = '2013/08/04 08:01:00 ', @enddate = '2013/08/04 11:21:00'
```

after you solve this, start solving other issues

--- edit ----

so you need to remove it from the parameters.

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[ParkingDeatailsReportnew] 
    @startdate nvarchar(100),@enddate nvarchar(100)
```

Why did you have it in the first place?
I doubt that it worked at all `execute` requires `VARCHAR`, you have use [`sp_executesql`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) when you use `NVARCHAR`

I also think that you have other errors in your logic, but you'll get there later.

Comment: i dont want to pass locid,,i want to take locid automatically from location table

Comment: sir i given like this and i passed my locid like this:and  locid IN  ' + (select l.Locid from Location_tbl l) but now am getting error:Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: that is because you have a subquery `'''and locid = '(select l.Locid from Location_tbl l)` and `Location_tbl` has more than one row. this could be the reason that  you had it as a parameter in the first place, so you should try to return the parameter and use `'''and locid =  ' + convert(nvarchar(), @locID) + '''`.

Comment: i want to take all locid from location table automatically

Comment: so you need to make change the where from `=` to `n` something like `'''and locid in  (' + (select l.Locid from Location_tbl l) 
 + ' )`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one -

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ParkingDeatailsReportnew] 

    @locid INTEGER, 
    @startdate NVARCHAR(100), 
    @enddate NVARCHAR(100)

AS BEGIN

    DECLARE
          @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
        , @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SELECT @cols = STUFF((
        SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(Vtype)
        FROM dbo.VType_tbl
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')

    SET @query = '
    SELECT Date, ' + @cols + '  
    from  ( 
        select v.Vtype, convert(date, dtime) as Date 
        from Transaction_tbl t 
        join VType_tbl v on t.vtid = v.vtid  
        where dtime between ''' + @startdate + ''' 
            and ''' + @enddate + '''
            and locid =  ' + CAST(@locid AS VARCHAR(10)) +
    '  ) d pivot ( count(Vtype) for Vtype in (' + @cols + ')  ) p '

    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @query
END
```